# Python's freeze.py doesn't install on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been looking for the `freeze.py` utility which is supposed to come bundled with Python 3 in a Python 3.3 Windows install (albeit with `distribute` and `pip` installed) and haven't found it. The utility can be downloaded directly out of the Python svn repository [here](http://svn.python.org/view/%2acheckout%2a/python/trunk/Tools/freeze/freeze.py), but I'm wondering: does `freeze` come with a standard Windows Python 3 install?

Comment: That utility gets installed into the `Tools` directory, not the directory that gets added to your path. I can't remember where that is on Windows, but on not-Mac POSIX it's $prefix/share/doc/python3.3/examples/Tools/freeze/freeze.py, and on Mac POSIX it's $framework/Versions/3.3/share/doc/python3.3/examples/Tools/freeze/freeze.py, so if you don't see `Tools` directly in the Python3.3 directory on Windows, try looking for directories named `doc`, `examples`, or similar to look inside.

Comment: Also, IIRC, Python also creates a `Scripts` directory on Windows, which contains some things that are in other places (e.g., the same `bin` directory as `python` itself) on POSIX.

Comment: And even more also… have you tried a `dir /s`?

Comment: @abernet - Even worse, I actually downloaded the file and it crashed on line 148. Do you know what is wrong there?

Comment: Without you telling me what file you downloaded from where, how you tried to run it, and what you mean by "crashed" (exited with an exception traceback? if so, what's exception? if not, what?), no, I have no idea what is wrong there. But meanwhile, you didn't answer my question: have you tried a `dir /s`? If you don't know what that means, or how to do it, I can explain.

Comment: @abernet - I get this error: File "freeze.py", line 148; except IOError, why:; SyntaxError: invalid syntax (I used semicolons to separate output lines and omitted where it showed what character was wrong).

Comment: I also have no idea what a `dir /s` is.

Comment: OK, that particular `SyntaxError` comes from using code that was written for Python 2.5 or earlier with Python 3.0 or later. Presumably the `freeze.py` that comes with 3.3 will work with 3.3, but you're trying to use one that's too old.

Comment: As for `dir /s`: Do you know how to use the Windows command prompt? And the `dir` command? The `/s` flag means "include subfolders". So, you can open a command prompt, then `cd C:\Python33` (or wherever you've installed it), then `dir freeze*.* /s /b`, it will show you where `freeze.py` is, or prove that it isn't anywhere.

Comment: @abernet - Good grief, I probably used a dead link from a old Python 2 question to get that code file. A search of the recent CPython Mercurial repository found [this folder](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/09811ecd5df1/Tools/freeze), which contains a bunch of `freeze` related code. I'll figure it out tomorrow. What a mess.

Comment: Kaboom. I downloaded all the code to the directory I'm working in and got the same error. I have to find an actual working copy of Python 3.3 `freeze`. Man. UPDATE: Trying a download from the 3.3.1 source mirror at http://hg.python.org/releasing/3.3.1/file/8e5812b35480/Tools/freeze, wish me good luck.

Comment: No dice, your puzzle for the day is: `Error: needed directory C:\Python33\lib\python3.3\config not found`. Like I said, I am running this from a standard Python 3.3 Windows install (with `distribute` and `pip` installed).

Comment: @abarnert - Looks like while I typed all of the previous comments, I typo'd your name. Whoops. You want to move this to chat?

Comment: First, a quick tip: You can take any URL at the hg repo and replace the tag with an x.y version number, and get the latest for that version. So, http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Tools/freeze will be the latest pre-3.3.2 code (as of today), which will _almost always_ work with any 3.3.x version (because bug fix releases aren't supposed to break backward compat).

Comment: But I'm pretty sure I've found the actual problem, so let me post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like Windows binary installations of Python don't come with the `freeze` tool. And there's apparently a good reason for this. According to the `freeze` [README](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Tools/freeze/README#l194) in the source tree:

> Under Windows 95 or NT, you *must* use the -p option and point it to the top of the Python source tree.

If you read the whole section, it comes down to this: On Windows, `freeze` only works if you've built Python from source, and have the resulting tree sitting around to be used for freezing. So, there's no good reason to give you `freeze` in binary installations.

---

Meanwhile, I probably should have asked this in the first place, but… are you sure you want `freeze` in the first place?

The freeze utility is very out of date (you might have guessed that from the README talking about requiring VC++ 5.0, Windows 95 or NT 4.0, etc.). It also never worked that well on Windows (as you can tell from the [documentation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze) describing it as a utility "… to compile executables for Unix systems"). And there's just a lot of things it can't handle, or handles badly. At this point should probably be considered more as example code than as a useful tool.

There are a number of third-party alternatives out there: [`cx_freeze`](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net), [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org), [`PyInstaller`](http://www.pyinstaller.org), etc. If you [search PyPI for "freeze"](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=freeze&submit=search) (and other terms that seem reasonable), you will find a bunch of these alternatives. If your goal is to create a standalone executable out of your Python script (which, btw, `freeze` can never do on Windows anyway), experiment with a few of these and pick the one you like best.

If your goal is something different, the right tool will be different—you might be better off using `venv` or just zipping up a user site-packages directory or creating a local PyPI server.

---

In the comments, you said:

> What I was actually looking for is a tool to convert Python code to C code. Apparently, that's impossible.

It's not *impossible*, it's just not what `freeze` (or its successors/competitors) does. [Cython](http://www.cython.org) compiles almost a strict superset of Python to C code, although it's C code that uses Python runtime objects (except where you explicitly statically declare variables and functions with C types). If C++ is an acceptable alternative to C, [Shed Skin](http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/) compiles a restricted subset of Python 2.6 (using native C++ objects, and using type inference so you don't have to statically declare your types).

The question is why you want to compile Python code to C.

If you're looking to optimize some slow code, Cython is great at speeding up small pieces of bottleneck code. It takes a bit of effort (deciding what to move to Cython, what static type declarations to put in, etc.), but the curve of payoff to effort is pretty solid. Shed Skin takes a lot less effort—if it works, it just speeds up everything, automatically—but it also means you can't write a lot of idiomatic Python code in the first place. But really, before looking at either, you should consider [PyPy](http://pypy.org), a complete implementation of Python 2.7.3 (and hopefully 3.3 soon) in a JIT-compiling interpreter, that often offers similar speedups, with pretty much no tradeoffs at all. Or, alternatively, you may just need to rewrite slow code to take advantage of already-optimized libraries (`numpy` instead of mapping over lists, `itertools` instead of explicit loops, `lxml` instead of `html.parse`, …).

If you're looking to write Python code that can interact directly with C code, without all the headaches of `ctypes` (or manually building Python bindings), Cython scores again. Cython code can effectively natively call both Python code and C code, and the compiler makes it all work like magic.

If you're looking to get C code that you can read, maintain, and improve on… there, you're out of luck. And this one may actually be impossible. Idiomatic Python code is just so different from idiomatic C code that it's hard to imagine how you could translate one into the other.

---

If you're wondering what the underlying problem is:

As far as I can tell, `freeze` makes a lot of assumptions about how things are laid out. It should be enough to have any Python installation that can build C extension modules and embedding apps, but it's not, because `freeze` goes under the covers and expects that building to work in specific ways. A standard binary installation on almost every *nix platform ends up looking like what `freeze` expects,* but a standard binary installation on Windows looks completely different.

It's not impossible to hack things up using Windows symlinks (at least if you have Vista or later and a drive with a modern version of NTFS) to get everything organized the way `freeze` expects (I found a blog where someone did that with 2.7.1…), but really, I don't think it's worth trying. It will be a lot of work (especially if you're just learning this stuff), and there's no guarantee you won't immediately run into another problem.

* This isn't actually true. On a Mac, both Apple's pre-installed Python and the binary installers at python.org actually give you the files organized as a Mac framework—but they provide a bunch of symlinks that simulate the traditional layout, which is good enough. On most linux distros, and many other platforms, the binary python package doesn't include any of the development files at all—but once you install an add-on binary package named something like python-devel, then you've got the right layout. Anyway, none of this matters to you, because if you wanted to learn about dpkg dependencies or framework builds you wouldn't be using Windows, right?

Comment: What I was actually looking for is a tool to convert Python code to C code. Apparently, that's impossible.